Show a unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equivumerous
Let $\mathbb{S}^2$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$,i.e.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{S}^2 := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}
\end{align*}
Show that $\mathbb{S}^2 $ and $ \mathbb{R}$ are equinumerous.
Idea: I need to show there is a bijection from $\mathbb{S}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is a map $f : \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Can I have some hints to set up my function? I think in my function $S^2$ should be $[0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$ but how can I design my function? Need helps, thanks.

Can you show both have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R^2$?

Do you know Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein? Or is this intended to be solved without that?

@J.W.Tanner Yes, I have shown both have same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}^2$

@Malady It need to show there is a bijection function between $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Just show there is a function maps from $(0,1) \to [0,1]$. Then there is a inverse maps

This is my method. Since $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, we have $\vert S^2\vert  \leq \vert \mathbb{R}^3 \vert = c$. On the other hand, the function $f : (0,1) \to S^2$ is defined as $f(t) = (\cos\pi t, \sin\pi t, 0)$ where $t \in (0,1)$. $f$ is an injection. Hence, $\vert S^2 \vert \geq \vert (0,1) \vert = c $. By the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem, we have $\vert S^2 \vert  = c$ which implies $S^2 \sim \mathbb{R}^3$.

In what sense does $\mathbb{S}^2=[0,180^\circ]\times[0,360^\circ]$?

@Malady consider the Spherical Coordinate system, then since r=1, we have the domain

Indeed it's much easier to use Schröder–Bernstein than to literally construct a bijection. Although I think you meant to write $S^2 \sim \mathbb{R}$ at the end. (Though what you wrote is true too, of course.)
